# Python Beginners: Creating dynamic class objects with dynamic attributes with loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to create some simple objects that are defined dynamically through a class - to allow me to rapidly iterate through the creation of all possibilities of these objects.

```
class NSObjects:
    def __init__(self, shape, position, shading):
        self.shape = shape
        self.position = position
        self.shading = shading

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.shape(), self.position(), self.shading())


def NSGenerator_1():
    for i in range (0,3):
        obj_1_i = NSObjects(shape_init_top + i, posn_init_top+i, shading_init_top+i)

    for i in range (3,6):
        obj_1_i = NSObjects(shape_init_mid + i, posn_init_mid+i, shading_init_mid+i)

    for i in range (6,9):
        obj_1_i = NSObjects(shape_init_mid + i, posn_init_mid+i, shading_init_mid+i)

NSGenerator_1()
print(obj_1_2)
```

At the moment it is telling me that obj_1_2 doesn't exist. For the purpose of this you can assume that I have defined all the init variables to start at 0, 1 or 2 elsewhere in the code. I am basically trying to create a series of objects which will have properties as defined by a mathematical formula.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide (I only started coding a few weeks ago so this might be a very silly question!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever assigned to `obj_1_i`, not `obj_1_2`, and it was local to the function. There is no way for Python to tell that the `_i` was meant as a separate variable instead of part of the longer variable name. For a quick fix, try replacing the
`obj_1_i =` parts with `globals()[f'obj_1_{i}'] =`.

---

But rolling numeric indexes into the variable names like that (`_1_2`) is a code smell. A better design is to actually use them as indexes to a data structure, like a list or dict.

For example, define
`obj = {}` at the top level (outside of any class or function).

Then you can replace `obj_1_2` everywhere with `obj[1, 2]`, etc. If you wrote them that way,
`obj[1, i]` would work as you expect inside those for loops.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense - I need all the style tips I can get!